# Creating a dynamic button in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a project in react and redux.  It includes a table that is formed through user input, so the user adds information into text fields, which are then added as rows on to the table.  I want to be able to click each of those rows to invoke a fairly basic function(its the same function for all the rows, and doesn't alter state). The function is included like this:

```
<tr onClick={() => this.editShow()}>
```

However when I click on the row, nothing happens!  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you `bind` `editShow` to the class?

Comment: Check the console. Any errors? Do some `console.log`s inside `this.editShow()` to see if it really doesn't fire.  Posting the code of  `this.editShow()`  would probably help people here help you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind event to your React component `<tr onClick={this.editShow.bind(this}>`
Or if you nedd to pass the parameters in method you can bind it in constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.editShow = this.editShow.bind(this);
 }
```